# Best algorithm for multi dimensional searching in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search, tree

I have been experimenting with an application and i have this problem. I have a list of rules like the ones given below. This is experimental data and real data has many more fields (30+). Every record can contain some values and some empty values. This is a list of lists but i can also hold it in a defaultdict (if it helps). Some 1 million records.

```
Age  Gender  City    Religion  Propensity
23   *       Delhi   *         0.33
*    M       Mumbai  *         0.78
*    *       *       Hindu     0.23
34   F       Chennai *         0.33
...
...
...
```

Now i have one dataset - (23, M, Delhi, Hindu) which has all values.

I need to choose all the records from the above table which matches this record even with one dimension at the fastest possible speed arranged in descending order by the number of dimensions. So row 3 and 1 match in this case. So the records which have least number of empty values will be at the bottom.

I need a sophisticated way of achieving this which works on scale inside python. Can't use any other software.

Comment: Is offloading the work to SQL an option? If not, do you have column indexes (fast lookup by column value) over the data (or does python offer that natively)?

Comment: Use a database and create indexes.

Comment: 1 million records, and no database? If you ask me, you have a serious problem then.

Comment: Can you use the [`sqlite3` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) which is built into Python?

Comment: You already have a database, and you will be reinventing query methods, better to use http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect with the ":memory" storage method if you really "can't use a db".

Comment: Will you be doing many such queries at once or very few?

Comment: Will try sqlite and below method. BTW how will you draft the above thing in a SQL Query ? Don't you need to manually make all combinations.... SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (age=23 AND GENDER=M AND city = * AND Religion = *) OR (....) OR (...)  etc.

Comment: @jim ... many many of them and require very fast results.

Comment: Instead of going through all combinations just do `(age=23 OR age=*) AND (gender=M OR gender=*) AND …`

Comment: In your example you were matching against all values. Will your search record ever contain missing values for any field?

Comment: You wrote, "So row 3 and 1 match in this case". Doesn't row 2 also match on Gender = 'M'?

Comment: @jim missing values are marked by *. No all values in the row should match the query to be selected

Comment: @AdityaSingh, sorry if I wasn't clear the first time. Let me use an example. Your gave a match dataset as (23, M, Delhi, Hindu). Can the record to match ever contain '*' (or any type of wildcard), like (23, M, *, Hindu) or (23, M, None, "Hindu"), etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in a set of dictionaries:

```
dict1:age->list<entry>
dict2:gender->list<entry>
...
```

Now, when you get a query - all you have to do is create a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) (map:entry->integer) sort it according to value and print it in descending order.

The run time is `O(d*m + mlogm)` (on average), where `d` is the number of lists (dimensions),  `m` is the number of output entries.

**pseudo-code:**

```
assume  list of dictionaries, let it be L:
printRelevants(entry):
   histogram <- new dictionary
   for each dimension d:
      l <- L[d].get(entry[d])
      for each element e in l: #remember to check for null l first
         val <- histogram.get(e)
         if val is null:
             histogram.put(e,1)
         else:
             histogram.put(e,val+1) #assuming overriding old entry with the same key
    #done creating the histogram! 
    sort histogram according to value
    print keys of histogram in descending order
```

Comment: @GarethRees not if `m==0`. Of course, you can't have zero output.

Comment: @GarethRees `O(...)` is a set of functions. The sets `O(mn+n)` and `O(mn)` are different if `m==0`. `O(mn)` contains only bounded functions if `m==0`. Even if a set "equals" any its element, you need to be more careful if both sides are sets.

Comment: @Jan: *m* is a variable here. See [Wikipedia on the definition of big-O when there are multiple variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables).

Comment: @JanDvorak: It doesn't make sense to say "if `m==0`" here. Big-O notation is about how a function behaves when all its inputs tend to infinity.

Comment: @GarethRees strange... I would think the input vector could diverge in any direction, not that all components had to diverge.

Comment: Note that if you let the input diverge in any direction, then your equality does not hold.

Comment: @Jan: it's just a notational convention, but it's worth learning, if only  to avoid misunderstandings like you had here.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming your "search criteria" is always the same, i.e. the "dataset" *(age,gender,city,religion)***

Move it to a dictionary of lists (or of sets) indexed by your "dataset"

```
result_dict = {}
for record in record_list:
    # you have to know the indexes
    # I'm assuming 0=Age, 1=Gender, 2=City, 3=Hindu
    key_data = []
    for index in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
        key_data.append(str(record[index]))
    key = ','.join(key_data)
    try:
        result_dict[key].append(record)
    except KeyError:
        result_dict[key] = []
        result_dict[key].append(record)

# Find all records that match '23,M,Delhi,Hindu'
print result_dict['23,M,Delhi,Hindu']
```

But really, I'd probably have it stored in a database and just run SQL queries on it.

Comment: Where are you respecting the wildcards there?

Comment: Of course it does not consider wildcards. This * are just treated as any other value. Please see my disclaimer in bold.

Comment: How could this approach support this requirment: `matches this record even with one dimension`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do use a SQL database (sqlite3) as you mentioned in a comment, the SQL would look like this:

```
-- gives you the set of complete records
SELECT
    v0.*
FROM values v0
WHERE -- only full records
    v0.Age IS NOT NULL
AND v0.Gender IS NOT NULL
AND v0.City IS NOT NULL
AND v0.Religion IS NOT NULL
AND v0.Propensity IS NOT NULL


SELECT v1.*, 
    CASE v1.Age WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
    CASE v1.Gender WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
    CASE v1.City WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
    CASE v1.Religion WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
    CASE v1.Propensity WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as dimensions
FROM values v1
WHERE v1.Age = 23
OR    v1.Gender = 'M'
OR    v1.City = 'Delhi'
OR    v1.Religion = 'Hindu'
ORDER BY dimensions desc
```

Comment: Should i create indexes ? I guess will have to create an index on every column.

Comment: I was trying this - SELECT * FROM rules WHERE (age='23' OR age='*') AND (gender='M' OR gender='*') AND (city='mumbai' OR city='*') AND (religion='3' OR religion='*')

Comment: Takes 0.24ms for a query. If i create a compound index on all fields, it takes 0.34ms.

Comment: The above has an asterik in every second term OR age='[asterik]'

Comment: @AdityaSingh the where clause you're using will just select every single record. Pretend one record was all wild cards, it would show up in your query.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good answers here. I've written and tested some code.

First here is an naive implementation of the requirements:

```
import pprint

t = [
    [ 23,   None, 'Delhi',   None,    0.33 ],
    [ None, 'M',  'Mumbai',  None,    0.78 ],
    [ None, None,  None,     'Hindu', 0.23 ],
    [ 34,   'F',  'Chennai', None,    0.33 ],
]

rlen = len(t[0])

# None may require special handling
m = [23, 'M', 'Delhi', 'Hindu', None]

a = [[] for i in range(rlen+1)]

for r in t:
    s = sum([1 for i in range(rlen) if r[i] == m[i]])
    if 0 < s:
        a[s].append(r)

# Print rows from least matching to most matching (easy to reverse)
rtable = [row for n in a for row in n]
pprint.pprint(rtable)
```

The problem is we scan each row and check each element value. To avoid the need to sort at the end, we keep separate lists for each possible match count, then we flatten our list of lists for the final result. I expect this to perform about O(n) relative to the size of table, worse if we have a large number of matches (building a large result list will be slower than O(n), approaching O(n^2) as a worst case).

We can speed things up If we index the table. We can use one dict per column and combine columns using sets.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

# data table
TABLE = [
    [ 23,   None, 'Delhi',   None,    0.33 ],
    [ None, 'M',  'Mumbai',  None,    0.78 ],
    [ None, None,  None,     'Hindu', 0.23 ],
    [ 34,   'F',  'Chennai', None,    0.33 ],
]

# The index is a list of dicts, cdictlist.
# cdictlist is indexed by column number to get the column dict.
# The column dict's key is the data value of the column
def BuildIndex(table):
    rlen = len(table[0])
    rrange = range(rlen)
    cdictlist = [defaultdict(set) for i in range(rlen+1)]
    for ir in range(len(table)):
        r = table[ir]
        for ic in rrange:
            f = r[ic]
            cdictlist[ic][f].add(ir)
    return cdictlist


def multisearch(table, match, cdictlist):
    # rcounts is row counts, number of times columns have matched for a row
    rccounts = defaultdict(int)

    #rset is the result set, set of row indexes returned for this search
    rset = set()

    for ic in range(len(table[0])):
        cset = cdictlist[ic].get(match[ic], set())
        rset = rset.union(cset)
        for i in cset:
            rccounts[i] += 1

    # sort the list by column match count, original row index
    l = sorted((v,k) for (k,v) in rccounts.iteritems())

    # return list of rows, for each row we return (count, index, raw data)
    lr = [ [l[i][0], l[i][1]] + table[l[i][1]] for i in range(len(l)) ]
    return lr

def main():
    cdictlist = BuildIndex(TABLE)

    # None may require special handling
    match = [23, 'M', 'Delhi', 'Hindu', None]

    lr = multisearch(TABLE, match, cdictlist)
    pprint.pprint(lr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The performance will depend on how many records are returned rather than the size of the table. The set union operation will quickly become problematic for large number of matches. And a record matches if *any* field matches and one of the example fields is Gender, so we should expect at least half the rows to be returned.

This approach would work *much* better if you had to match all the columns. We might be able to improve this by building the set of records **NOT** returned (using set intersection), then filtering out those records.

Comment: Trying your stuff out. Have been messing with SQLite so far. On 30k records, it takes around 0.26ms. 0.40ms on 170k records and 0.50ms on 1 mil database with memory option turned on and creating a compounded index on all fields. Trying out some alternate approaches in python.

Comment: @AdityaSingh. Thanks. I expect SQLite in-memory could very well be the winner.

Comment: @AdityaSingh, I just realized it's probably faster to generate the set of records that are being excluded. I'll work on this when I have time.